# How to convert a string of hex values to ASCII

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, hex

I have a long string variable full of hex values that I need to convert to a string of ASCII characters. How do I do it?

**JavaScript code**

```
var _0x4697=["\x5A\x20\x31\x36\x28\x61\x2C\x73\x29\x7B\x4F\x20\x70\x3D\x31\x31\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x61\x29\x3B\x67\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x43\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x68\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x6C\x3D\x2D\x31\x3B\x64\x3D\x70\x2E\x58\x28\x22\x64\x22\x29\x3B\x4A\x3D\x70\x2E\x58\x28\x22\x4D\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x76\x28\x4F\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x4A\x2E\x44\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x68\x3D\x4A\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x71\x3B\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x75\x2E\x6D\x2F\x31\x30\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x31\x71\x2E\x31\x6F\x2E\x6D\x2F\x46\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x64\x2E\x6D\x2F\x31\x30\x2F\x46\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x7D\x39\x28\x6C\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x43\x3D\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x46\x20\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x4D\x20\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x22\x31\x63\x22\x20\x71\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x68\x2B\x27\x3F\x31\x62\x3D\x31\x61\x26\x31\x39\x3D\x30\x22\x20\x31\x38\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x31\x37\x3E\x3C\x2F\x4D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x43\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x31\x6B\x20\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x6B\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x64\x2E\x44\x3E\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x67\x3D\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x31\x65\x2D\x31\x66\x22\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x22\x31\x67\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x64\x20\x31\x68\x3D\x22\x31\x69\x22\x20\x31\x6A\x3D\x22\x31\x35\x22\x20\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x31\x6C\x22\x20\x71\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x64\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x71\x2B\x27\x22\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x67\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x6B\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x64\x2E\x44\x3C\x31\x29\x7B\x67\x3D\x27\x3C\x2F\x41\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x67\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x31\x6D\x20\x31\x6E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x67\x3D\x27\x27\x7D\x57\x2E\x31\x70\x3D\x5A\x28\x29\x7B\x4F\x20\x65\x3D\x31\x31\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x22\x31\x72\x22\x29\x3B\x39\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x73\x29\x7B\x57\x2E\x31\x74\x2E\x36\x3D\x22\x59\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x32\x2E\x6D\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x31\x77\x28\x22\x36\x22\x2C\x22\x59\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x32\x2E\x6D\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x38\x3D\x22\x31\x78\x2E\x2E\x21\x31\x79\x22\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x7C\x68\x32\x7C\x66\x61\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x7C\x70\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x74\x62\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x7C\x79\x6F\x7C\x7C\x7C\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x62\x72\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x6D\x65\x74\x61\x7C\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x7C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x6C\x61\x62\x65\x6C\x32\x31\x32\x7C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x31\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x63\x66\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x54\x61\x67\x73\x7C\x32\x30\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x7C\x63\x68\x61\x72\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x79\x6F\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x32\x32\x30\x7C\x72\x6D\x7C\x61\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x66\x75\x6C\x6C\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E\x7C\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x75\x6D\x7C\x76\x71\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x31\x7C\x64\x61\x69\x6C\x79\x6D\x6F\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x31\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x33\x38\x30\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x79\x6F\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x50\x6F\x73\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x6F\x6E\x7C\x76\x69\x6D\x65\x6F\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x79\x6F\x75\x74\x75\x62\x65\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x59\x6F\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];
```

Comment: Just put this exact code into the browser console and see what `_0x4697` is.

Comment: To what do you want to convert this code? And why?

Comment: I want to know the value of this variable

Comment: does not work on console

Comment: The value of the variable is a very long string. It's in quotes, so it already is a string.

Comment: Well, it's a String in an array, otherwise, yes

Comment: that's the problem. Is there a way to know  string?

Comment: sorry, I am beginner, table ascii ?

Comment: @LucaKiebel Yes, but I didn't want to complicate the issue. :)

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that you want to take the hex values and figure out their ASCII values, to get a string of readable characters?

Comment: yes , is it okay ?

Comment: I've edited your question to better explain what you want. (Do I understand what you want?)

Comment: yes, ok @BobRodes

Answer (score 1):

A bit more clarification would help. Do you want to convert `0x4697` to decimal? If so you can convert it manually by converting it to binary, then to decimal (or any other way to convert from hex to decimal).

Or you can try [this online tool](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) that takes hex and returns decimal. Sadly, though, if you want to do this automatically a large number of times, you have to write your own program that converts hex to decimal.

If that's not what you want, please clarify.

**EDIT: If you want to convert this hex code to ASCII characters, just copy the variable declaration and initialization into your JavaScript console, then type the name of the variable in the console. It will display the ASCII value of the hex code (at least it does in the Chrome JS console)**

Comment: We've been working on clarifying what the OP wants in the comments. It looks like he wants to convert the hex values to ASCII characters.

Comment: Then he could just place it in the console. it works :I

Comment: Hmm. In the comments that was suggested and the OP said it "didn't work." Maybe he didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

As Saif says, you can do this directly in the console. If you prefer, you can also add this line of code after yours:

```
var _0x4697 = ["your long array of strings"];
console.log(_0x4697);
```

If you do this, you'll be able to see the ASCII strings in the console. For more information on how to use the console with Chrome, see [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are incorrect. Your code has several JavaScript string literals. They use `\xXX` escapes. In JavaScript, [\xXX escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are for the ISO 8859-1 character encoding (aka "Latin-1").

JavaScript (as well as Java, .NET, VB4/5/6, …) strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. UTF-16 is one of several character encodings for [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Unicode is a superset of ISO 8859-1 so there is nothing to be gained by using `\xXX` escapes.

JavaScript offers several types of escapes. One of which is `\xXX`, for historical reasons. Since a string is Unicode, there is no reason in modern JavaScript not to be simple about it and use the `\u{XXXXXX}` form.

It looks like the strings are JavaScript code themselves. JavaScript code doesn't use ASCII. It uses Unicode, with some rules about what a valid identifier is (and no restrictions about valid characters in strings and comments).

Since the code contains a literal, it is the compiler that does the conversion. You don't get a chance. You can see that you if print the value of the variable to the console.

```
console.log( _0x4697);
```

```js
var _0x4697=["\x5A\x20\x31\x36\x28\x61\x2C\x73\x29\x7B\x4F\x20\x70\x3D\x31\x31\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x61\x29\x3B\x67\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x43\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x68\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x6C\x3D\x2D\x31\x3B\x64\x3D\x70\x2E\x58\x28\x22\x64\x22\x29\x3B\x4A\x3D\x70\x2E\x58\x28\x22\x4D\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x76\x28\x4F\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x4A\x2E\x44\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x68\x3D\x4A\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x71\x3B\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x75\x2E\x6D\x2F\x31\x30\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x31\x71\x2E\x31\x6F\x2E\x6D\x2F\x46\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x68\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x64\x2E\x6D\x2F\x31\x30\x2F\x46\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x6C\x3D\x69\x3B\x42\x7D\x7D\x39\x28\x6C\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x43\x3D\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x46\x20\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x4D\x20\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x22\x31\x63\x22\x20\x71\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x68\x2B\x27\x3F\x31\x62\x3D\x31\x61\x26\x31\x39\x3D\x30\x22\x20\x31\x38\x3D\x22\x30\x22\x20\x31\x37\x3E\x3C\x2F\x4D\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x43\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x31\x6B\x20\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x6B\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x64\x2E\x44\x3E\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x67\x3D\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x31\x65\x2D\x31\x66\x22\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x22\x31\x67\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x64\x20\x31\x68\x3D\x22\x31\x69\x22\x20\x31\x6A\x3D\x22\x31\x35\x22\x20\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x31\x6C\x22\x20\x71\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x64\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x71\x2B\x27\x22\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x67\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x6B\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x39\x28\x64\x2E\x44\x3C\x31\x29\x7B\x67\x3D\x27\x3C\x2F\x41\x3E\x27\x3B\x70\x2E\x38\x3D\x67\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x48\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x47\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x49\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x66\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x78\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x34\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x50\x20\x51\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x52\x28\x70\x2E\x38\x2C\x53\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x41\x2F\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x76\x2D\x77\x22\x3E\x31\x6D\x20\x31\x6E\x20\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x55\x2D\x56\x22\x3E\x3C\x6A\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x35\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x6B\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x37\x2D\x54\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x23\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x63\x20\x63\x2D\x37\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x75\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x6A\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x22\x4E\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x79\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x7A\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x7D\x6E\x20\x67\x3D\x27\x27\x7D\x57\x2E\x31\x70\x3D\x5A\x28\x29\x7B\x4F\x20\x65\x3D\x31\x31\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x22\x31\x72\x22\x29\x3B\x39\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x73\x29\x7B\x57\x2E\x31\x74\x2E\x36\x3D\x22\x59\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x32\x2E\x6D\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x31\x77\x28\x22\x36\x22\x2C\x22\x59\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6F\x2E\x31\x32\x2E\x6D\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x38\x3D\x22\x31\x78\x2E\x2E\x21\x31\x79\x22\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x7C\x68\x32\x7C\x66\x61\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x7C\x70\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x74\x62\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x7C\x79\x6F\x7C\x7C\x7C\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x62\x72\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x6D\x65\x74\x61\x7C\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x7C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x6C\x61\x62\x65\x6C\x32\x31\x32\x7C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x31\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x63\x66\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x54\x61\x67\x73\x7C\x32\x30\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x7C\x63\x68\x61\x72\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x79\x6F\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x32\x32\x30\x7C\x72\x6D\x7C\x61\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x66\x75\x6C\x6C\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E\x7C\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x75\x6D\x7C\x76\x71\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x31\x7C\x64\x61\x69\x6C\x79\x6D\x6F\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x31\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x33\x38\x30\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x79\x6F\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x50\x6F\x73\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x6F\x6E\x7C\x76\x69\x6D\x65\x6F\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x79\x6F\x75\x74\x75\x62\x65\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x59\x6F\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];
console.log( _0x4697);
```